# Django rest framework viewsets method return HTTP 405 Method Not Allowed

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, rest, django-rest-viewsets

I am developing a cart api where add item in cart and remove. I craete a CartViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet) and also create two method in CartViewSet class add_to_cart and remove_from_cart..But when I want to add item in cart using add_to_cart and remove using romve_from_cart method then got HTTP 405 Method Not Allowed.I am beginner in building Django rest api.Please anyone help me. Here is my code:

my configuration:

```
Django==3.1.1
djangorestframework==3.12.0
```

models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from product.models import Product
from django.conf import settings
User=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL

class Cart(models.Model):
    """A model that contains data for a shopping cart."""
    user = models.OneToOneField(
        User,
        related_name='user',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

class CartItem(models.Model):
    """A model that contains data for an item in the shopping cart."""
    cart = models.ForeignKey(
        Cart,
        related_name='cart',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        null=True,
        blank=True
    )
    product = models.ForeignKey(
        Product,
        related_name='product',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    quantity = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=1, null=True, blank=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return '%s: %s' % (self.product.title, self.quantity)
```

serializers.py:

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import Cart,CartItem
from django.conf import settings
from product.serializers import ProductSerializer

User=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL

class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'email']

class CartSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    """Serializer for the Cart model."""

    user = UserSerializer(read_only=True)
    # used to represent the target of the relationship using its __unicode__ method
    items = serializers.StringRelatedField(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Cart
        fields = ['id', 'user', 'created_at', 'updated_at','items']
            

class CartItemSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    """Serializer for the CartItem model."""

    cart = CartSerializer(read_only=True)
    product = ProductSerializer(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = CartItem
        fields = ['id', 'cart', 'product', 'quantity']
```

views.py:

```
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework import viewsets
from rest_framework.decorators import action

from .serializers import CartSerializer,CartItemSerializer
from .models import Cart,CartItem
from product.models import Product
class CartViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """
    API endpoint that allows carts to be viewed or edited.
    """
    queryset = Cart.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CartSerializer

    @action(detail=True,methods=['post', 'put'])
    def add_to_cart(self, request, pk=None):
        """Add an item to a user's cart.
        Adding to cart is disallowed if there is not enough inventory for the
        product available. If there is, the quantity is increased on an existing
        cart item or a new cart item is created with that quantity and added
        to the cart.
        Parameters
        ----------
        request: request
        Return the updated cart.
        """
        cart = self.get_object()
        try:
            product = Product.objects.get(
                pk=request.data['product_id']
            )
            quantity = int(request.data['quantity'])
        except Exception as e:
            print (e)
            return Response({'status': 'fail'})

        # Disallow adding to cart if available inventory is not enough
        if product.available_inventory <= 0 or product.available_inventory - quantity < 0:
            print ("There is no more product available")
            return Response({'status': 'fail'})

        existing_cart_item = CartItem.objects.filter(cart=cart,product=product).first()
        # before creating a new cart item check if it is in the cart already
        # and if yes increase the quantity of that item
        if existing_cart_item:
            existing_cart_item.quantity += quantity
            existing_cart_item.save()
        else:
            new_cart_item = CartItem(cart=cart, product=product, quantity=quantity)
            new_cart_item.save()

        # return the updated cart to indicate success
        serializer = CartSerializer(data=cart)
        return Response(serializer.data,status=200)

    @action(detail=True,methods=['post', 'put'])
    def remove_from_cart(self, request, pk=None):
        """Remove an item from a user's cart.
        Like on the Everlane website, customers can only remove items from the
        cart 1 at a time, so the quantity of the product to remove from the cart
        will always be 1. If the quantity of the product to remove from the cart
        is 1, delete the cart item. If the quantity is more than 1, decrease
        the quantity of the cart item, but leave it in the cart.
        Parameters
        ----------
        request: request
        Return the updated cart.
        """
        cart = self.get_object()
        try:
            product = Product.objects.get(
                pk=request.data['product_id']
            )
        except Exception as e:
            print (e)
            return Response({'status': 'fail'})

        try:
            cart_item = CartItem.objects.get(cart=cart,product=product)
        except Exception as e:
            print (e)
            return Response({'status': 'fail'})

        # if removing an item where the quantity is 1, remove the cart item
        # completely otherwise decrease the quantity of the cart item
        if cart_item.quantity == 1:
            cart_item.delete()
        else:
            cart_item.quantity -= 1
            cart_item.save()

        # return the updated cart to indicate success
        serializer = CartSerializer(data=cart)
        return Response(serializer.data)

class CartItemViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """
    API endpoint that allows cart items to be viewed or edited.
    """
    queryset = CartItem.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CartItemSerializer
```

urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path,include
from rest_framework import routers

from .views import (CartViewSet,CartItemViewSet)

router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'carts', CartViewSet)
router.register(r'cart_items',CartItemViewSet)

urlpatterns = [
    path('',include(router.urls))
]
```

Comment: What was the URL that you have tried to access?

Comment: http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/carts/product_id/add_to_cart/

Comment: when i send put request then return "detail": "Not found.". and not add item in cart.

Comment: What was the error response you have got?

Comment: HTTP 404 Not Found

Answer (score 3):

When you create a ModelViewSet for `Cart` then your API will be `/api/carts/cart_id/add_to_cart` (i.e. `cart_id`, not `product_id`).

So, I believe you get `Not found` error because there is no such a cart with that ID you pass there.

I think your architecture isn't good in the first place. I don't think you should create `Cart` and `CartItem` models. Items that a user puts into a cart is a temporary data, just store this information in `localStorage` on the frontend.

And just have an endpoint to checkout all these selected products: `POST /api/checkout/`. Where you'll send product IDs and their quantity.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am a beginner but I will try to change my coding architecture. And try to use localStorage for temporary data.